# PHP session_set_save_handler and mysqli call to a member function prepare() error

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I need to write session into DB with PHP. So I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    access int(10) unsigned,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and this function:

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost";
$titulo="config";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$bd="store";
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd) or die(mysqli_error());

session_set_save_handler('_open','_close','_read','_write','_destroy','_clean');

function _open() {
    GLOBAL $mysqli;
}

function _close() {
    GLOBAL $mysqli;
}

function _read($id) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE  id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num>0) {
        $record = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $record['data'];
    }
    return "";
}

function _write($id, $data) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli;

    $access = time();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $id, $access, $data);
    $stmt->execute();
}

function _destroy($id) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}

function _clean($max) {
    GLOBAL $mysqli;

    $old = time() - $max;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE access < ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

My problem is, when I include this page above and call session like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["user"]   = "josh";
```

It is not recording in my sql table and usually give me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
in C:\xampp\htdocs\session.php on line 41
```

line 41 is in `_write` function.

So, I need help to make it work, to record this data on session table. What is wrong in my code?

edit:

var_dump:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.6.16" ["server_version"]=> int(50616) ["stat"]=> string(136) "Uptime: 8072 Threads: 1 Questions: 41520 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 463 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 85 Queries per second avg: 5.143" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(7756) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\session.php on line 43
```

Comment: Seems like you're getting an error when you do `$mysqli = new mysqli`. Add `or die(mysqli_connect_error())` to that line.

Comment: nothing different happened

Comment: What does `var_dump($mysqli)` show when the error happens?

Comment: I edit my question with var_dump output!

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting that error. `var_dump` clearly shows that `$mysqli` is an object. Check your code for typos.

Comment: var_dump($mysqli) inside _write function do not show me any results. it appears that session is not calling _write

Comment: If it's not calling `_write` how can it be getting an error in that function?

Comment: yeah, you are right! it's strange, no record in db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this line before session_start():

```
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

[PHP manual recommends to do this.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Genius! Thank you.